# Combining 2 private sub worksheet change, macro vba

Tags: excel, vba

I search before in this site, but not really found same case with my code. Hope someone here can help me on this. How to combine two Private sub below?

1)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target = Range("k2") Then
        Range("D4").Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

2)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$D$4" Then filtra
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

One Sub two tests:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'exit if >1 cell
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 then Exit Sub

    If Target.Value = Me.Range("k2").Value Then
        Me.Range("D4").Value = ""
    End If

    If Target.Address = "$D$4" Then filtra

End Sub
```

Comment: Here's a +1 for adding the check for more than 1 cell.

Comment: Changing D4 will trigger another Worksheet_Change which runs filtra.

Comment: Excelent! @Tim Williams

Comment: @user10959770 - maybe that's the intent?